# android.intent.action.VIEW won't open my app

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to setup functionality for a user to use the Android camera app to scan a QR code to open my Android app. If the user doesn't have my app installed, the fallback is to open a webpage that will prompt them to get it.

I have this in my android manifest:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
        <data android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:host="myhost" />
    </intent-filter>
```

If I run

```
adb shell am start -d https://myhost
```

I get a prompt on the Android device asking if I want to use the app or Chrome to open the link, which is great.

**However**, if I run

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d https://myhost
```

(specifying VIEW as the action) it opens the webpage in Chrome, and returns the following:

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://myhost... }
Status: ok
LaunchState: COLD
Activity: com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity
TotalTime: 349
WaitTime: 351
Complete
```

Likewise, if I use the Android camera to scan a QR code with the same URL, it opens the webpage in Chrome.

So even though I explicitly have `android.intent.action.VIEW` in my intent-filter, it opens the link in chrome instead of opening my app.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? There are a few other asks here on Stack Overflow from people trying to do something similar, but they're using custom schemes with unusual formatting, and I'm just using plain old https.

Comment: First, there is no single "the Android camera". There are dozens, if not hundreds, of pre-installed camera apps, let alone user-installed ones. Second, there is no requirement for a QR code scanner to use `ACTION_VIEW` to launch an arbitrary app -- they are welcome to limit it to Web browsers if they choose. Beyond that, have you [set up `assetlinks.json` for your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing#associatesite), to declare that it handles your domain?

Comment: I haven't set that up yet. I'll take a look! Thanks!

Comment: reading up on that it looks like setting up assetlinks.json would just make it skip the step of asking which app I want to use to open the link. But when I open the link via QR code it doesn't ask me that, it just goes straight to chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the package of your app.

Let's say the package name of your app is `com.example.myapplication`

Then run the command as follows

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://myhost" "com.example.myapplication"
```

Comment: thanks! that fixed the adb shell call. But how do I make my app the default for VIEW action calls to `"https://myhost"` instead of Chrome?

Comment: In that case, you need to set up the assetlinks.json file

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working! The solution ended up being a combination of a bunch of different answers I found in various places, and I had to implement them all for it to work.

My final `intent-filter` looks like this:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https"
        android:host="myhost"
        android:pathPrefix="/"
        />
</intent-filter>
```

notably, it won't work without the `android:pathPrefix="/"`! There has to be **something** for path prefix, even if it's just `/`.

Additionally, following the instructions here: https://doordash.engineering/2022/01/25/your-deep-links-might-be-broken-web-intents-and-android-12/
...I created an `assetlinks.json` file and added it to our backend. (Thanks to CommonsWare and Anisur for that tip!). I'd thought that the `assetlinks.json` only served to make your app the default for opening those kinds of links (skipping the app browser), but apparently as of Android 12 it's **mandatory**.

I'd tried those (and a whole bunch of other things) individually and in various combinations, but this is the combination that finally made it work; `assetlinks.json` on the backend, and `android:pathPrefix="/"` in the intent-filter (along with all those other things in the intent-filter).

Hopefully this will help someone else in the future! (probably me. I will probably forget this in a few days, and will need to do this again years from now and come back to this and be very happy.)